# Syncing backups to cloud storage

Tags: backup, mysql

I am about to embark on a project which will require a lot of documentation and since I have a spare Pi, I think it would be really useful to use it to store this documentation in a `custom MySQL database`.  Now of course this is very important information to me and I don't want to lose it so what I want to do is back the database up daily and then upload that to some sort of cloud storage.  I prefer `OneDrive` but `Dropbox` would do as well.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  I don't really want to install any sort of client, all I want a script to do is grab the latest MySQL backup, and upload it to perhaps a shared directory on one of the aforementioned cloud services.

I found the below link which I'll try, so if anyone has used it and can provide feedback, that would be good.

https://github.com/fkalis/bash-onedrive-upload

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should be possible.

For that purpose I would write a simple shell script which consists of 2 parts:

1. Create a backup of the database
2. Upload that database dump to `%cloudStorage`

Then I would set up a daily cronjob that executes that script.

You can try to search for something like `mysqldump` for part 1, and `bash upload dropbox` for part 2. Check also the documentation about `cronjob`  to automate the process.